# fade in page after page loaded with spinner

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to fade in the whole page after its loaded,

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(function() {
            $('html').fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>


<html style="display:none">
....
<body>
.....
</body>
</html>
<div id="overlay">
     <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
     Loading...
</div>
```

The problem is the loading image doesn't show

what should I do?

Comment: When do you actually call the loading image?

Comment: The div is supposed to be inside your html tag, as is everything else (including the script tag)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Instead, try putting the contents of body into a containing div: `<div id="content">...</div>` hide that, show your loader, etc.

Comment: add the overlay to the `html` tag and hide the `body` instead

Comment: Also, I do believe `bind` is deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The loader is in the HTML block, which has display:none. So it won't display. (even though you put it outside of it)

Instead, create a container DIV with display:none, hide that & fade it in, instead of the HTML.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(function() {
            $('#container').fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="overlay">
         <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
         Loading...
    </div>
    <div id="container" style="display:none">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```